# SQL query returning not all data w.r.t to Territory Name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get Sales Person's data w.r.t Territory they work. I'm Using Adventureworks database tables Employee, Contact, SalesPerson, SalesTerritory.
Here is my query :

```
Select p.FirstName, p.LastName, h.EmployeeID, t.Name as "Territory Name"
from Person.Contact p  
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee h ON p.ContactID = h.ContactID
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson s ON  s.SalesPersonID = h.EmployeeID  
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory t ON s.TerritoryID = t.TerritoryID
```

Issue with this query is it results exactly one Territory. However there are sales persons who work in multiple territories... I need to result all of them.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that Sales.SalesPerson have one entry per TerritoryID?

Comment: No not all SalesPerson has entry per Territory ID but some SalesPerson are having association with 1 or more Territory/ID

Comment: Which AdventureWorks database?  I have 2008R2 and the table names don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You must mean you want to know where Employees worked over time.  As far as I can see in AdventureWorks2008 and AdventureWorks2008R2, Sales.SalesPerson is assigned a single TerritoryID, then in Sales.SalesTerritoryHistory there can be multiple TerritoryIDs per BusinessEntityID.  For those DBs, use this:

```
select      p.FirstName
            ,p.LastName
            ,e.LoginID -- there is no EmployeeID in this version of AdventureWorks
            ,st.Name                        as [TerritoryName]
from        Sales.SalesPerson               as sp
join        Person.Person                   as p
on          p.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
join        HumanResources.Employee         as e
on          e.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
join        Sales.SalesTerritoryHistory     as sth
on          sth.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
join        Sales.SalesTerritory            as st
on          sth.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID
-- keep the where clause if you want to find only current TerritoryIDs
-- remove the where clause if you want to know all across time
where       GETDATE() between sth.StartDate and isnull(sth.EndDate,'9999-1-1')
```

Clarify the version of AdventureWorks DB and I can correct the error (but don't say 2012, cause I ain't installing SQL Server 2012 :)

Comment: I'm having AdventureWorks2008R2_RTM version. And yes, I missed to provide details I'm looking for salesPerson from SalesTerritoryHistory. Exactly what I'm looking is SalesPerson with all above information and having Sales Territory history associated with them.